# Rails not allowing me access an objects attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is driving me nuts and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I'm retrieving an object through its associations in a form. I want the result that's saved to display information from its related object. I know the object is being retrieved but I can't access its attributes:

When I do the following:

```
<%= mp.object.margin.inspect %>
```

I get the following printed:

```
#<Margin id: 1, margin_low: 0, margin_high: 0, created_at: "2015-09-10 16:05:43", updated_at: "2015-09-10 16:05:43", description: "A draw">
```

But when I change it to the following:

```
<%= mp.object.margin.description %>
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
undefined method `description' for nil:NilClass
 <div class="col-md-4"><%= mp.object.margin.description %></div>
```

What the hell am I doing wrong? I've checked my relationships and they look fine. I can't understand how an object can be returned with the 'description' attribute in it but I cannot access it.

Thanks for looking

> **Edit 1 SOLVED**

Ok, I'm doing something stupid doh!. There are certain objects where no margin gets returned and that's what's causing the problem. I've been looking at this computer for too long :)

I'll delete the post in 20 minutes

Answer (score 1):

In Rails you can guard yourself against `no method errors` on nil by using [`try`](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try).

```
mp.object.margin.try(:description)
```

Or

```
mp.try(:object).try(:margin).try(:description)
```

However this is pretty flagrant violation of the **law of Demeter**:

> - Each unit should have only limited knowledge about other units: only units "closely" related to the current unit.
> - Each unit should only talk to its friends; don't talk to strangers.
> - Only talk to your immediate friends.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter